# Iterate through one column in a datatable to find matching values, then add to list to output to view

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatable, ado.net

I have data from an SQL table being shown in a view.  The table has the following:
    Authorise(AuthoriseID,TransactionID, TransactionName, AccountID, AccountName, Match)
The TransactionID and AccountID are repeated several times but only once together (They come from two different tables that has been joined through a matching function).

Currently I have an ActionResult HTTPGET which uses a stored proceudre to "Select * from Authorise order by TransactionID".  Everything from the table is returned to the user.  I only want rows for a certain TrnsactionID.  The user then will accept or reject (sends the rows to other tables in the database).  Once all the rows of that TransactionID are complete it will move to the next TransactionID and all the rows with that TransactionID.  The rnsactionID will change so the first TransactionID displayed to the user just depends on what is the first ID.

My question is, how do I loop through one column in a datatable, get matching values, only display those rows and then move to the next ID once all rows have been authorised?

I know I would need to set the first TransactionID to a variable and then loop through the datatable, if any of the other values in that column match the variable then add to a list...I just cant seem to get it right.  I have tried a few things and its not looking right.  This is one attempt -

This is my code for the Controller (It all works when sending all data to the view):

```
public ActionResult Authorise()
```

{

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbpath"].ToString());

List<AuthoriseModel> AuthoriseList = new List<AuthoriseModel>();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetAuthorise", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();



foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
{
    string CurrentUID = dtRow["TransactionID"].ToString();

    if (dtRow["TransactionID"].ToString().Equals(CurrentUID))
    {


        AuthoriseList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows

                         select new AuthoriseModel()
                         {
                             AuthoriseID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AuthoriseID"]),
                             TransactionID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TransactionID"]),
                            TransactionName = Convert.ToString(dr["TransactionName"]),
                             AccountID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AccountID"]),
                             AccountName = Convert.ToString(dr["AccountName"]),
                             PercentMatch = Convert.ToString(dr["PercentMatch])

                         }).ToList();
    }
}



return View(AuthoriseList);
```

}

This list will then only display rows with that same TransactionID, once all rows have been dealt with and removed from then it will move to the next TransactionID?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Everything from the table is returned to the user. I only want rows for a certain TrnsactionID."* Why not use a `WHERE`?

Comment: @Larnu I don't have a where because there is no clause, I can't specify a TransactioID to show as they will always be different, I just want to display it per TransactionID.  I still want it to display everything, just at different times, per TransactionID.  Can this be done using WHERE?

Comment: Yes, you would parametrise the query, so you pass the transaction id you want from the application, as a parameter, to the query.

Comment: @Larnu I would never know the TransactionID though, the TransactionId it starts of with will be whatever the first TransactionID is in the list.  If I was to do that I would have to use one get request to get all rows from the table, then identify what the first TransactionID is, then another get request with the passed in TranscationID to get all the other records with the same TransactionID.  It just seems like that is a lot more work than trying to figure out a loop through the column to finding matching TransactioIDs?